# How to set decimal? or string on Field property in Blazor DevExpress DataGridColumn?

Tags: c#, razor, blazor, devexpress, razor-pages

I need to set a Field with a decimal? value, if doesn't have value it should show the "-".

I tried use this code:

`Field="@(nameof(this.DataDTO.EventDefaultValue > 0 ? this.DataDTO.EventDefaultValue.ToString("F2") : "-"))"/>`

But doesn't is possible convert, the Visual Studio show the error

[image]

I'm using the Blazor, together with DevExpress DxDataGridColumn component.

How can I to resolve this point? Someone can help me?

Comment: You probably have multiple errors in this line of code (for example: I don't see what good you would get from `nameof("-")`). However, the first one you are pointing out is because `EventDefaultValue` is a nullable decimal (`decimal?`), therefore, to access its value you should get through `Value` first: `this.DataDTO.EventDefaultValue.Value.ToString("F2")`. You should make some research about `nameof` and `Field` because I am quite sure this is not how it is supposed to be used in `DxDataGridColumn`.

Comment: Yes, the `nameof()` was wrong, and in the solution I needed to use `Value`, thank you for suggestion. To remainder of logic I needed to use the `<DisplayTemplate />`component.

Answer (score 1):

`nameof()` method is used to get the name of a method, or a class for example. But you use it with some logic inside, so it will hit an error.

The parameter `Field` is generally use - for example in the Telerik Library's components - to target a field of a class. I am pretty sure it is exactly the same here, you wanna give the name of the field of your class that the column you set is reffered to. For example `Field="@nameof(DataDTO.EventDefaultValue)` will tell to Blazor "this column will display the EventDefaultValue field of the object".

Comment: Exactly, about the `nameof()` I fixed this point. And finnaly I found a solution using DisplayTemplate. I put the solution below.

Answer (score 1):

As it is the comment above the use of `nameof()` was wrong. I removed the `nameof()` and used `DisplayTemplate` component to set a field in my grid and pass a data of context.

As I needed to make a condition verification the `DisplayTemplate` was a good solution.

The code was this below:

```
 <DxDataGridColumn Caption="@Localizer["Valor Default"]"
                              Field="eventDefaultValue">
                              <DisplayTemplate>
                                  @{
                                    var summary = context as CostEventTypeSummaryDTO;
                                    if (summary.EventDefaultValue != null && summary.EventDefaultValue > 0)
                                    {
                                        <span>@summary.EventDefaultValue.Value.ToString("F2")</span>
                                    }
                                    else { <span>-</span> }
                                  }
                              </DisplayTemplate>
            </DxDataGridColumn>
```

And this result was this below:

[image]

Comment: For your information, for nullable types, you can also check if they have a value with `HasValue`.